# Create RabbitTemplate without TracingMessagePostProcessor

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-sleuth

I use Spring Cloud Sleuth integrated with Spring AMQP to enable `traceId` when publishing messages.

Sleuth automatically adds `TracingMessagePostProcessor` into `RabbitTemplate.beforePublishPostProcessor` to add trace headers to outgoing Rabbit messages.

I have a scenario: I have a batch of objects and want to publish them, like this:

```java
List<Object> listObj = getData(...);
for (Object o : listObj) {
  rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(exchange, routingKey, o);
}
```

When I consume messages, all messages have same `traceId`. I don't want this.

How can I create just a `rabbitTemplate` bean without `TracingMessagePostProcessor`? Or how to make every message I publish/consume have a different `traceId`?

I already have read the Spring Cloud Sleuth docs. I can use the config...

```
spring.sleuth.messaging.rabbit.enabled=false
```

...to disable this feature, but I just want to disable it for a specified `rabbitTemplate` bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in Open Zipkin Brave is like this:

```
 /** Instruments an existing {@linkplain RabbitTemplate} */
  public RabbitTemplate decorateRabbitTemplate(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    MessagePostProcessor[] beforePublishPostProcessors =
      appendTracingMessagePostProcessor(rabbitTemplate, beforePublishPostProcessorsField);
    if (beforePublishPostProcessors != null) {
      rabbitTemplate.setBeforePublishPostProcessors(beforePublishPostProcessors);
    }
    return rabbitTemplate;
  }
```

Since it is unconditional, I'd suggest you to override `RabbitTemplate`  for that `setBeforePublishPostProcessors()` method and have its body empty or just remove that `TracingMessagePostProcessor` before propagating to `super`.

Comment: How can I remove TracingMessagePostProcessor? RabbitTemplate have no method getBeforePublishPostProcessors().

Comment: Correct. That's why I suggested to extend `RabbitTemplate` and override its `setBeforePublishPostProcessors()` to exclude provided `TracingMessagePostProcessor`. There is `removeBeforePublishPostProcessor(MessagePostProcessor)`, but I doubt it is going to be easy to find a `TracingMessagePostProcessor` instance from Brave. It is just an inner instance and is not exposed somehow: https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/master/instrumentation/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/brave/spring/rabbit/SpringRabbitTracing.java#L301

Answer (score 0):

I use `RabbitTemplate.addBeforePublishPostProcessors` to remove header `b3` from message properties headers

```
@Autowired
public void removeTraceProcessor(RabbitTemplate noTraceRabbitTemplate) {
    noTraceRabbitTemplate.addBeforePublishPostProcessors(
        message -> {
            message.getMessageProperties().getHeaders().remove("b3");
            return message;
        }
    );
}
```

---

Second solution from @Artem-Bilan

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate noTraceRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connFactoryLocal) {
    return new RabbitTemplate(connFactoryLocal) {
        @Override
        public void setBeforePublishPostProcessors(MessagePostProcessor... beforePublishPostProcessors) {
            super.setBeforePublishPostProcessors(
                Arrays.stream(beforePublishPostProcessors)
                .filter(p -> !p.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("TracingMessagePostProcessor"))
                .toArray(MessagePostProcessor[]::new)
            );
        }
    };
}
```